# Polifilm Wrap Stuck in Hood-Vent

Tags: plastic, range-hood

The Hood-Vent was accidentally installed with the polifilm protective wrap on each part. There are exposed parts that cannot be pulled out without tearing the wrap because it is jammed in the other parts. I need to find a way to remove it COMPLETELY (not just cut) for aesthetic and also safety purposes as the film will be exposed to heat.

Comment: Disassemble it and re-do the job correctly.